# Jackson enum property does not get recognized

Tags: java, jackson

I have an enum like so :

```
public enum Type {
   @JsonProperty("private")Private, group, supergroup, channel    
}
```

the json file itself has private field so I need private (which is java keyboard)for serialization and mapping but If i use **private** with all lowercase that is a runtime error. I used @JsonProperty as above code but still does not work.

do you have any solution for this ?

here is the exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not
>   construct instance of com.mehdi.model.Chat$Type from String value
>   'private': value not one of declared Enum instance names: [Private,
>   group, supergroup, channel]  at [Source: /home/mehdi/Desktop/json.txt;
>   line: 14, column: 16] (through reference chain:
>   com.mehdi.model.Update["message"]->com.mehdi.model.Message["chat"]->com.mehdi.model.Chat["type"])
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException.from(InvalidFormatException.java:55)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.weirdStringException(DeserializationContext.java:742)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumDeserializer.deserialize(EnumDeserializer.java:91)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumDeserializer.deserialize(EnumDeserializer.java:20)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:525)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:99)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:242)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:118)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:525)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:99)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:242)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:118)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:525)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:99)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:242)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:118)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2993)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2052)
>     at com.mehdi.ff.Test.main(Test.java:25)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Please be more verbose about that "... but still does not work". What does it do? What does it not do?

Comment: @nop77svk I already put the exception ~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use **@JsonValue** inside the enum implementation.

```
public enum Type {

    Private("private"),
    Group("group"),
    Supergroup("supergroup"),
    Channel("channel")

    private String jsonValue;

    private Type(final String json) {
        this.jsonValue = json;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String jsonValue() {
        return this.jsonValue;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the hint of @Toilal I came up with this solution :

```
public enum Type {
    Private, group, supergroup, channel;
    @JsonValue
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString().toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: Both annotations are useless with this implementation.

Comment: toString() is used when @JsonValue is absent.

Comment: @Toilal when an enum want to get the string, it calls the toString method and the default toString method just return the exact enum alphabet, this trick will get the value of the enum from the super class: "Private", lowercase it "private", for solving the problem and the child enum override method calls for getting the lowercase value and finally that pass through Jackson as a JsonValue for json binding ~